# People having more than 1 million in their account

Tags: mysql, database

Lets assume we have 3 table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Persons (
  id int(10),
  name varchar(100),
  address varchar(100),
  age int(3),
  eyeColor varchar(100),
  gender varchar(100)
);
INSERT INTO Persons VALUES
(11,'Woody allen','Amsterdam',35,'green','male'),
(12,'Charlton Heston','Rome',68,'green','male'),
(13,'Katharine Hepburn','Rome',87,'brown','female'),
(14,'Rachel McAdams','Leipzig',70,'blue','female')
;

CREATE TABLE BankAccounts (
  id int(10),
  balance decimal(10,2)
);
INSERT INTO BankAccounts VALUES
(11,1600931.91),
(12,1437877.7),
(13,267971.26),
(14,949724.05)
;

CREATE TABLE AccountOf (
  id int(10),
  person_id int(10),  -- foreign key to Persons.id
  account_id int(10)  -- foreign key to BankAccounts.id
);
INSERT INTO AccountOf VALUES
(18,11,13),
(17,12,12),
(20,12,14),
(16,14,11),
(19,14,13)
;
```

I have to write a query that returns persons with more than 1 million euro in all their bank accounts.

I thought of the following:

```
SELECT name 
FROM Persons
JOIN BankAccounts ON BankAccounts.id=Persons.id
WHERE BankAccounts.Balance > 1000000
```

Any recommendation on how I could improve this code?
The expected result shoudl be

```sql
name
-------------------
Rachel McAdams
Charlton Heston
```

Comment: You are joining `Persons` into `Persons` instead of joining `BankAccounts` table

Comment: And also missing a join of `AccountOf`; from your structure,`Persons` cannot be joined directly to `BankAccounts`.

Comment: The relation between database tables `Persons` and `BankAccounts` is many-to-many, correct? One person can have more than one account and there also can be joint accounts where several persons own the same account. Hence the `AccountOf` table, correct?

Comment: Do not deface your question by removing all the content. If the topic is closed, please delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name,
    SUM(ba.balance)
FROM Persons AS p
    INNER JOIN AccountOf AS aof
        ON aof.person_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN BankAccounts AS ba
        ON ba.id = aof.account_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING SUM(ba.balance) > 1000000
;
```

You can see the result in this [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tmD3G9AcL7Kji7ZsWFxsjx/0)

Comment: @TimLewis Sorry, but can't see your fork. At the link you provided, I can see only my query.

Comment: @TimLewis ok, understood. The SUM is necessary, as the question is about the amount on ALL their bank accounts. If I change the account balance for `BankAccounts.id` 12 and 14 to 500000 and 510000, with your query Charlton Heston is not returned in the resultset, while summing the balances of his accounts (12 and 14), he reaches a balance of 1.100.000

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying; if they have multiple accounts, you sum those to see if they have over 1 mil in all their accounts, rather than checking if one of their accounts has 1 mil on its own. Good call! Disregard my previous comments then!

Answer (score -1):

**It should be**

```
SELECT name 
FROM Persons
JOIN BankAccounts ON BankAccounts.id=Persons.id
WHERE BankAccounts.Balance > 1000000
```

**not**

```
SELECT name 
FROM Persons
JOIN Persons ON BankAccounts.id=Persons.id
WHERE BankAccounts.Balance > 1000000
```

because you used

```
FROM Persons JOIN Persons
```

your joining the same table.
you should join **BankAccounts**

Comment: Read the comments, the join should be over the AccountOf-Table

Comment: yeah i changed that after the comment but that didn't give me the expected result. i have added an image, have a look. maybe I should be using something like HAVING    SUM(balance) >= 1000000

Answer (score -1):

Your sql is wrong, it should be :

SELECT name
FROM Persons
JOIN BankAccounts ON BankAccounts.id=Persons.id
WHERE BankAccounts.Balance > 1000000

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Consider [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) the SQL in your answer. You can edit it.